# I mean an intellij error like below, when I try to run junit

Tags: intellij-idea

I use the latest intellij, with latest hybris plugin. And today when I try to run the junit, then have following error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating [Hybris Integration](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7525-hybris-integration) plug-in to 2020.2.1.7+ version:

> Bug fix. JUnit didn't work with hybris projects on java 8.